# Can I use a DateTimePicker from @material-ui/pickers without having to render a TextField?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would like to use the `DateTimePicker` component from `@material-ui/pickers` without having to render a `TextField`. In the designs for the feature I am working on, the date picker is brought up by pressing a button, not a text field.

It seems that the picker is always rendered as a `TextField`. When focused, the actual date/time picker shows up.

The documentation shows an example of how to programmatically open the picker https://material-ui-pickers.dev/guides/controlling-programmatically. The problem is that it still comes with a `TextField`.

I have also seen you can use individual pieces of the picker like `Calendar` or `ClockView` to build your own. Ideally, I'd rather avoid reinventing the wheel as much as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Just put a text field on the page and hide it.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I thought of that. I was wondering if there was a cleaner way of doing it without adding invisible stuff to the DOM.

Comment: "I'd rather avoid reinventing the wheel as much as possible." <-- You are not reinventing the wheel. Calendar and ClockView are standard gui components which you can use in your "custom" elements.
IMHO, reinventing the wheel it is when you are creating new calendar component which is already exists in the lib.